# Format string value like date in google chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, google-visualization

I am doing an app in angular and google charts, I have a data extracted from GraphQL that return an array with date and two values, the first row correspond to field names in the array:

```
myArray = [
        ["Date", "upx", "upn"],
        ["2017-02-01", 0.031, 2],
        ["2017-02-02", 0.051, 1],
        ["2017-02-03", 0.041, 6],
    ]
```

After getting the data from graphQL, I have an array of arrays similar to previous code, I am converting this array to DataTable with google visualization arrayToDataTable:

```
let data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(myArray);
```

I have a file with configurations to specify pattern formatters for each chart and column position of date field like this:

```
 google: {
  type: 'LineChart',
  options: {
    isStacked: true,       
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Date',
      type: 'date',
      format: 'MMM/dd/yy'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Absenteeism',
      format: 'percent',
      gridlines: {
        count: 10
      },
      step: 1,
    }
  },
  formatters: {
      date: [
        {
          columnNum: 0,
          pattern: '"MMM/yyyy"
        }
      ],
      number: [
        {
          columnNum: 1,
          pattern: '#.##',
          fractionDigits: 2
        }      
      ]
    }
}
```

So I am passing this configuration to function that draw the chart:

```
<div [chartData]="data" [chartFormatters]="google.formatters" [chartOptions]="google.options" [chartType]="google.type" GoogleChart></div>
```

Now I am trying to conver the string to date but doesn't work:

```
for (var formatType in chartFormatters) {
    switch (formatType) {
      case 'number':
        chartFormatters[formatType].forEach(ItemFormatter => {
          let formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(ItemFormatter);
          formatter.format(data, ItemFormatter.columnNum);
        });
        break;
      case 'date':         
        chartFormatters[formatType].forEach(ItemFormatter => {            
          let formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat(ItemFormatter);
          formatter.format(data, ItemFormatter.columnNum);
        });
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

How I can convert string to date format in my first array, My problem is that I have many queries returning similar data from graphql to draw chart using the same function in angular, but date field is not present in all results or not are in the same position for all queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the values in the date column need to translate to actual dates,

before the formatter will work, the array would need to look something like...

```
myArray = [
  ["Date", "upx", "upn"],
  [new Date("2017-02-01"), 0.031, 2],
  [new Date("2017-02-02"), 0.051, 1],
  [new Date("2017-02-03"), 0.041, 6]
];
```

Comment: Thank you @whiteHat, my problem is that the array come from graphql and I can change the format of date string cuz actually I don't know where is the date field, in 0 or 2 or 3 index in array.